# Subdomain instead of path for blog in Docusaurus v2

Tags: docusaurus

Is there a way to configure docusaurus v2 so the blog not is not configured as path but as subdomain?

Would like to achieve **blog.page.tld** instead of **page.tld/blog**.

Could not find a way to do that from [the documentation on how to integrate a blog into docusaurus v2](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/blog).

Answer (score 0):

Subdomains have nothing to do with Docusaurus. Subdomains are part of DNS configuration while Docusaurus is an application. You should look up your domain name manager and tweak it there.

Additionally, if you don't want the `/blog` path, you will have to use [blog-only mode](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/blog#blog-only-mode)